# WooCommerce product attribut randomly missing on some orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My client has a Wordpress website (3.8.3) with WooCommerce (2.1.5) and products (coffee) with custom attributes (blends).

Most of the time, clients orders end up without any problems. But about 10% of the time, the order is entered with a blank attribute for the blend (when you are not supposed to be able to add a product without the blend selected).

We have the same client, ordering the same product twice with one month between its 2 orders, one that worked fine where we can see the blend, and one with an empty blend.

Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Is that a js validation? Maybe the user has js turned off.

Comment: Doesn't look like it, as the same user did the same order twice, and one had no problems. (and after a try with JS turned off, you can't add items into your cart)

Comment: Can you post an url that has the add to cart button and the blend validation?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an old browser that doesn't do jquery validations. You might need to switch to non-jquery style validation:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate_me();">
```

If that doesn't sound like fun you could just send them whichever blend is most popular with really old people who never update their PC.